# HTML validation and ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: html, asp.net, validation

I'm experimenting with HTML built-in validation attributes and the first difficulty I have run into is that the validation attributes work in a form context. I.E. if you want to validate two independent inputs then you should put those inside two different `<form>` tags.

How do I handle this situation with ASP.NET where the page is formed by a big form containing the whole content?

Comment: I also have this problem. I use webforms with angularjs. I have multiple forms on the same page with independent validation at the same time. I haven't solved this, but I see two solutions. 1. Change to ASP.NET MVC or.. 2 Skip html validation attributes and create my own attributes with directives inside angularjs. I'll get back to you when i'm done...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding.

HTML 5 has both `form` and `input` validation attributes.  The `form` attributes simply allow you to turn on/off autocomplete and completely turn off validation of all of the `input` elements.

The `input` elements are where the real work is performed.  Note that you can have autocomplete turned on at the `form` level, but have it turned off for particular `inputs`.

BTW, having nested `<form>` tags is still a no no under HTML5.  It's just that various browsers support it in order to continue to be compatible with the vast majority of sites that were coded incorrectly.  Actually, this concept, of being as compatible as possible, is the leading reason browsers are so complicated.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_attributes.asp

Comment: "Having multiple <form> tags is still a no no under HTML5"? Aren't you talking about multiple NESTED form-tags?

Comment: @HeNrik: Yes, that would have been a better way to state it.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: The following solution isn't beautiful, I know. But it's the only solution I can think of. :/

Create a form-tag side by side with the server-created form-tag. Position the client-side form on top of the page.

Drawback: You cannot use server tags. But hey... who does now a days?! :)

```
<form runat="server" ...>
    ... Everything ....
</form>
<div class="positionedOnTopOfThePage">
    <form>
        ... Form with HTML5 validation ...
    </form>
    <form>
        ... Form with HTML5 validation ...
    </form>
</div>
```